# spring internalization for values returned from controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have this message returned from controller i.e

```
model.addAttribute("Message", "This is the English version of this website");
```

currently its been displayed using line

```
[[${Message}]]
```

which will display above message. how to make above Message value internalization.so Message changes to diffrent languages

some thing like this

th:text="#{home.page.title}" >> will display title is many lang

how to do for [[${Message}]] multi language

Comment: you can send the key of message, not message: `model.addAttribute("Message", "messageKey")`. And in the html, using `[[#{__${Message}__}]]` to get i18n content

Comment: @ken2009 thats not working either                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
 String Message = "This is the English version of this website";
      model.addAttribute("Message", Message);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as the following steps:

1. In `messages.properties`:

   labels.my_label=This is the English version of this website
2. In Controller:

   model.addAttribute("Message", "labels.my_label");
3. In html (Thymeleaf):

   ```html
   <span th:text="#{__${Message}__}"></span>
   ```

or you can output directly as: `<span>[[#{__${Message}__}]]</span>`

4. If you want i18n:
   Add country to properties file, for example: `messages_en.properties` (English), `messages_vi.properties` (Vietnamese), `message_jp.properties` (Japanese), ...
   In `messages_en.properties`:
   labels.my_label=This is the English version of this website
   In `messages_<lang>.properties`:
   labels.my_label=Another text for specific language

Reference:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text

Comment: thank you for detail explanation. it worked like charm